# In Illustrator is it possible to remove/hide the wireframe outlines but keep the body of a 3D extruded object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

For reference I've attached a screenshot of what I'm talking about. I've extruded this object and applied gradients to it, but now I want to remove the black lines that form the wireframe but keep the main body part of the 3D object (the sections that are filled in with the gradients). Is this possible without undoing everything I have done?

Thanks in advance

[image: 3D object with wireframe outlines]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe..

`Select All` and set the **stroke** to `none` in the **Stroke Panel**.

If that doesn't work....

Try selecting *one* of the black areas with the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) and then choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` and set the **fill** to `None` in the **Color Panel**.

If neither of those work....

...then you'll need to edit the 3D settings, which probably means starting over if you've already expanded the 3D effect. The black is there because you applied the 3D effect to objects which had a black stroke.

Comment: That second suggestion seemed to do the trick and got rid of most of them but not all of them. I'll play around with it and see if I can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: @Paddy it's possible the fills are *slightly* different colors. So you may need to do this a few times selecting areas which remain.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an expanded extrusion?

If yes, most of that expanded objects are in a clipping mask, if you go to **Menu Object** > **Clipping Mask** > **Edit Contents** and then delete, you keep the "body".

[image: Clipping Mask]